# Using NSKeyedUnarchiver to decode object to a new model class in Swift using Coddle

Tags: swift

I am working with an old Objective-C codebase that utilizes NSCoding, NSSecureCoding, and NSKeyedUnarchiver/NSKeyedArchiver to store a model in User Defaults. We are migrating to a new User Defaults layer and I am wondering if it possible to decode this object without having the underlying class. For instance, the current object being stored is `UserModel`. Is it possible for me to create a new class, `NewUserModel`, with the same properties then decode this object from User Defaults?

I have tried the following, see comments for results:

```
guard let userData: Data = UserDefaults.default.object(forKey: "user-data") else {
   return nil
}

// This returns the object, but it is Any as we do not have the model class for this object
guard let restoredObject = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(userData) as? Any else {
   return nil
```

}

```
let unarchiver: NSKeyedUnarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: userData)

if let decoded = unarchiver.decodeTopLevelDecodable(NewUserModel.self, forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) {
   // this fails and does not decode the object even though the properties are identical
   print(decoded)
}

// trying to access the properties individually also fails
if let userToken: String = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "userToken") {
   // fails
   print(userToken)
}

// attempting to decode using JSONDecoder also fails as the data is not valid JSON
do {
   let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
   let user = try jsonDecoder.decode(NewUserModel.self, from: userData)
   print(user)
} catch {
   print(erro)
}
```

Basically I have the underlying data yet I need to decode this data manually to get the relevant information without having access to the exact class that was used to archive the data.

Comment: The APIs are deprecated. With the current `NSKeyed(Un)archiver` APIs you must specify the model class. And consider that there is `data(forKey:)` and `string(forKey:)` in `UserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for me to create a new class, NewUserModel, with the same properties then decode this object from User Defaults?

**Yes.**

See the [`-setClass:forClassName:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/1414659-setclass?language=objc) method, which is described thus:

*Sets a translation mapping on this unarchiver to decode objects encoded with a given class name as instances of a given class instead.*

So you can use that method to tell your unarchiver to instantiate `NewUserModel` whenever it sees the class name `UserModel` in the archive.

There's also a class method [`+setClass:forClassName:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/1409718-setclass?language=objc) that does the same thing for *all* unarchivers, which might be handy if you have to read the same data in multiple places.

Comment: Unfortunately, after I set `unarchiver.setClass(NewUserModel.self, forClassName: "UserModel")`, the decoded object is nil. I guess that is progress as the attempt to decode does not error out.

Comment: @kschins Makes sure that NewUserModel adopts NSCoding, of course. Also, you might need to look at the data to see what name was used to encode the data; it’s possible that “UserModel” isn’t the right name.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in `-[NewUserModel initWithCoder:]` and see if a) you hit it, and b) it succeeds or returns nil.